# HTML tags to JSX React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, html-parsing, jsx

I'm doing a call to an API that returns some HTML:

example:

```
<p>Hello there</p><p>Javascripti</p>
```

I want to use this in my React Native app but this time I want to replace all the `<p>` tags for `<Text>` because that is something I can use in React Native.

How can I achieve something like this? I can't find out how to translate or parse HTML.

EDIT: I used Regex to make the `<p>` a `<Text>` but it just returns a string. It displays this on the screen: `<Text>Lorem Ipsum</Text`. How can I parse this to readable JSX?

Comment: have you tried regex?

Comment: I replaced the p tags with Text tags. But I still have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSX is basically syntax sugar (as seen [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects), [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) and [especially here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)) for calling `createElement`:

```
React.createElement(component, props, ...children)
```

So once you've captured the text inside the `<p></p>` tags you can generate any tag like this:

```
let capturedContent = 'Hello there'

const element = React.createElement('Text', { }, capturedContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be used here:

**Tags changed**

```
const myRegex = /(<p>|<\/p>)/g;
const myHtml = '<p>Hello there</p><p>Javascripti</p>';

myHtml.replace(myRegex, 'Text');
```

**Then place this into your React-Native render for your jsx. It would be something like this. I do not know your full setup so apologies:**

```
render() {
 return (
  {myHtml}
 )
}
```

Comment: I just replaced the p tags with Text. But it still returns a string. So it displays: <Text>Hello World</Text> on the screen (it prints the tags to the screen). Also: /p/g replaces every 'p' with 'Text'. Also the 'p' in Javascripti. So I've used /<p>/g and /<\/p>/g

Comment: @Raiders I edited my question. Sorry i did that regex quickly.